# different schema types for the same xml element depending on attribute

Tags: schema, xsd, jaxb

the xml looks like

```
<root>
<service name="product" />
<service name="sim" />
<service name="blub" />
</root>
```

the schema should look like

```
<xs:element name="root">
<xs:complexeType>
<xs:element type='serviceProduct' name='service' />
<xs:element type='serviceSim' name='service' />
<xs:element type='serviceBlub' name='service' />
</xs:complexeType>
</xs:element>
```

Is it possible with JAXB Bindings to do that? I cannot change the xml but I would like t to have different java classes for product, sim, blub but its all the same xml element.

With class binding declerations it is possible to change the class name but how could I do this for the same element but with different attributes?

Thanks,
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be here ... [Java/JAXB: Unmarshall XML attributes to specific Java object attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284786/java-jaxb-unmarshall-xml-attributes-to-specific-java-object-attributes)

but I would prefer a solution in the schema. It could work as described in the 'Bind Choice Example' which shows how to bind a choice model group to a Java Interface ... http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp155808

The problem with this solution is that the @bindingStyle attribute is no longer allowed as of JAXB 2.0.

Any ideas?