# Xml List to Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, list, jaxb

What way JAXB give to convert this type of XML conversion

```
<options>
  <option name="name">https://abc.com/</option>
  <option name="name2">https://abc.com/</option>
</options>
```

I created two object classes for it. It does not fill object with data and set null values for  tag where it should set URL like https://abc.com/.

`Options.java` and `Option.java`

`Options` class contain this setter

```
  @XmlElement(name = "option")
  public void setOption(List<Option> option) {
    this.option = option;
  }
```

**Option.java** class is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "option")
public class Option {

  String name;

  String option;

  public Option() {
    super();
  }

  public Option(String name, String option) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.option = option;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getOption() {
    return option;
  }

  public void setOption(String option) {
    this.option = option;
  }
```

Comment: Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284786/java-jaxb-unmarshall-xml-attributes-to-specific-java-object-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlValue` annotation on the `option` property of the `Option` class.