# JAVA/JAXB : Marshal/UnMarshal using attributes in the xml or class members

Tags: jaxb

I have XML as follows

```
<request type="1">
    <request-header/>
    <request-details>
    <!--  Some more tags -->
    </request-details>
</request>
```

For mapping this XML I have class structure as follows :

```
public class Request1
{
    private RequestDetail_1;
    //other members
}

public class Request2
{
    private RequestDetail_2;
    //other members
} 

public class RequestDetail_1
{
    //members
}

public class RequestDetail_2
{
    //Members
}
```

What I want to do is ... If attribute type is 1 then I need to create object of type Request_1 , if type is 2 then object type will be Request_2 and so on.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284786/java-jaxb-unmarshall-xml-attributes-to-specific-java-object-attributes) link for reference but still couldn't figure out a way to do this. I want to use pure JAXB and not MOXY or any other such frame works... :( .

Partial code :

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RequestAdaptor.class)
@XmlRootElement(name="request")
public class AuthRequest extends Request
{
    private AuthRequestDetails requestDetails;

    public RequestDetails getRequestDetails() 
    {
        return requestDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRequestDetails(RequestDetails requestDetails) 
    {
        this.requestDetails = (AuthRequestDetails)requestDetails;
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AuthRequestDetails extends RequestDetails
{
    @XmlElement(name="user-name")
    private String userName;
    @XmlElement(name="password")
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RequestAdaptor.class)
public abstract class Request 
{
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String type;

    @XmlElement(name="request-header")
    protected RequestHeader requestHeader;

    public RequestHeader getRequestHeader() 
    {
        return requestHeader;
    }

    public void setRequestHeader(RequestHeader requestHeader) 
    {
        this.requestHeader = requestHeader;
    }

    public String getType() 
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) 
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public abstract void setRequestDetails(RequestDetails requestDetails);

    public abstract RequestDetails getRequestDetails();


}

public class RequestAdaptor extends XmlAdapter<RequestDTO, Request>
{
    @Override
    public RequestDTO marshal(Request v) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println("marshal");
        RequestDTO lRequestDTO= new RequestDTO();
        lRequestDTO.setRequestHeader(v.getRequestHeader());
        lRequestDTO.setType(v.getType());
        if(v.getType().equals("5"))
        {
            AuthRequest lRequest = (AuthRequest)v;

        }
        else
        {
            PingRequest lRequest = (PingRequest)v;
        }
        return lRequestDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public Request unmarshal(RequestDTO v) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println("unmarshal");
        if(v.getType().equals("5"))
        {
            AuthRequest lRequest = new AuthRequest();
            lRequest.setRequestHeader(v.getRequestHeader());
            lRequest.setType(v.getType());
            return lRequest;
        }
        else
        {
            PingRequest lRequest = new PingRequest();
            lRequest.setRequestHeader(v.getRequestHeader());
            lRequest.setType(v.getType());
            return lRequest;
        }
    }

}
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RequestDTO 
{
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String type;

    @XmlElement(name="request-header")
    private RequestHeader requestHeader;

    @XmlElement(name="request-details")
    private RequestDetails requestDetails;

    public RequestHeader getRequestHeader() 
    {
        return requestHeader;
    }

    public void setRequestHeader(RequestHeader requestHeader) 
    {
        this.requestHeader = requestHeader;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public RequestDetails getRequestDetails() {
        return requestDetails;
    }

    public void setRequestDetails(RequestDetails requestDetails) {
        this.requestDetails = requestDetails;
    }

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RequestHeader 
{
    @XmlElement(name="name")
    String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

First thing is  : Marshal and Unmarshal of Adaptor is not getting called. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: The answer given in the question you have linked does not use Moxy. The usage of `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` is pure JAXB.

Comment: @Victor That answer is also not relevant here. Update: I am wrong it is relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java/JAXB: Unmarshall XML attributes to specific Java object attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284786/java-jaxb-unmarshall-xml-attributes-to-specific-java-object-attributes)

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Show us your code, how far did you managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a StAX `XmlStreamReader` to parse the XML.  Then advance it to the root element.  When it's at the root element event check the value of the `type` attribute.  Use this value to determine which `Class` you should pass to the `unmarshal` method that takes a `Class` and `XmlStreamReader` to get the result you are looking for.