# Adding a property to a unique XMLElement in a POJO with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have to build an XML containing several elements. I have such elements to build this XML part

```
<ram:SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement>
  <ram:BuyerOrderReferencedDocument>
    <ram:LineID>1</ram:LineID>
  </ram:BuyerOrderReferencedDocument>
  <ram:NetPriceProductTradePrice>
    <ram:ChargeAmount>60.0000</ram:ChargeAmount>
    <ram:BasisQuantity unitCode="C62">1.0000</ram:BasisQuantity>
  </ram:NetPriceProductTradePrice>
</ram:SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement>
```

I created POJOs for SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement, BuyerOrderReferencedDocument, NetPriceProductTradePrice...

```
@Getter @Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement {
    @XmlElement(name = "BuyerOrderReferencedDocument", namespace = NamespaceMapper.RAM_URI)
    private BuyerOrderReferencedDocument buyerOrderReferencedDocument;
    @XmlElement(name = "NetPriceProductTradePrice", namespace = NamespaceMapper.RAM_URI)
    private NetPriceProductTradePrice netPriceProductTradePrice;
}

@Getter @Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BuyerOrderReferencedDocument {
    @XmlElement(name = "LineID", namespace = NamespaceMapper.RAM_URI)
    private String lineId;
}

@Getter @Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class NetPriceProductTradePrice {
    @XmlElement(name = "ChargeAmount", namespace = NamespaceMapper.RAM_URI)
    private String chargeAmount;

    @XmlElement(name = "BasisQuantity", namespace = NamespaceMapper.RAM_URI)
    private String basisQuantity;
}
```

My issue is concerning `<ram:BasisQuantity unitCode="C62">1.0000</ram:BasisQuantity>`
I found that we can use XMLAttribute annotation

```
@Getter @Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IssueDateTime {
    @XmlElement(name = "DateTimeString", namespace = NamespaceMapper.UDT_URI)
    private String dateTimeString;
    @XmlAttribute(name="format")
    private int format;
}
```

It generates this

```
<ram:IssueDateTime format="102">
  <udt:DateTimeString>20200115</udt:DateTimeString>
</ram:IssueDateTime>
```

Unfortunatelly, it's not exactly what i'm expecting.

Comment: You want to generate ram:BasisQuantity but your code is for ram:IssueDateTime. What are you expecting to generate?

Comment: I want to have this: <ram:BasisQuantity unitCode="C62">1.0000</ram:BasisQuantity>

Comment: You need to use XmlValue. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415136/jaxb-xmlattribute-xmlvalue-real-example

Comment: thanks ! i got it ! it works. I posted final code for this. –

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code thanks @pringi answer:

In SpecifiedTradeProduct

```
@Getter @Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SpecifiedTradeProduct {
    @XmlElement(name="GlobalId", namespace = NamespaceMapper.RAM_URI)
    private GlobalId globalId;

    ...
}
```

And I created the GlobalId class:

```
@Getter @Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GlobalId {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "SchemeId")
    private String schemeId;

    @XmlValue
    private String globalId;
}
```