# Exception : "Missing class indicator field from database row [UnmarshalRecordImpl()]." when unmarshalling XML using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, jaxb2, moxy

Is it any way to unmarshalling with @XmlDescriminatorNode/@XmlDescrimintatorValue annotations next XML, or any workaround:

```xml
<assets>
    <asset type="full">
        <data_file role="source">
            <locale name="ru-RU"/>
        </data_file>
        <data_file role="extension">
            <locale name="ru-RU"/>
        </data_file>
        <data_file>
            <locale name="ru-RU"/>
        </data_file>
    </asset>
</assets>
```

My mapping classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="data_file")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@role")
public abstract class BaseDataFile implements Serializable {

    @XmlPath("@role")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="data_file")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("source")
public class SourceDataFile extends BaseDataFile {

}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="data_file")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("source")
public class SourceDataFile extends BaseDataFile {

}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="data_file")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("extension")
public class SourceDataFile extends BaseDataFile {

}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="asset")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
public abstract class BaseAsset implements Serializable {

    @XmlPath("@type")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @XmlPath("data_file")
    private List<BaseDataFile> dataFiles;

    public List<BaseDataFile> getDataFiles() {
        return dataFiles;
    }

    public void setDataFiles(List<BaseDataFile> dataFiles) {
        this.dataFiles = dataFiles;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

The error occures if XML containes element as below, without **"type"** attribute:

```
<data_file>
  <locale name="ru-RU"/>
</data_file>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should help:

**JAVA MODEL**

**Super Class (`BaseDataFile`)**

Below is a simplified version of your `BaseDataFile` class.  Since you have mapped the XML attribute `role` as the inheritance indicator you do not need to also map it to a property in your object model.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorNode;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({SourceDataFile.class, ExtensionDataFile.class})
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@role")
public abstract class BaseDataFile implements Serializable {

}
```

If you really want to map the `role` XML attribute to a property in your object model you should use MOXy's `@XmlReadOnly` property to prevent it being marshalled to the XML document (it will already be wriiten as the inheritance indicator).

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorNode;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlReadOnly;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({SourceDataFile.class, ExtensionDataFile.class})
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@role")
public abstract class BaseDataFile implements Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlReadOnly
    String role;

}
```

**Subclass (`SourceDataFile`)**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorValue;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("source")
public class SourceDataFile extends BaseDataFile {

}
```

---

**MISSING INHERITANCE INDICATOR**

**Base Class is not Abstract**

If your base class (`BaseDataFile`) had not been abstract then if the inheritance indicator was missing an instance of the base class would have been created.

**Base Class is Abstract**

Since your base class is abstract MOXy complained about the missing inheritance indicator value:

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-44] (Eclipse Persistence Services - @VERSION@.@QUALIFIER@): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class indicator field from database row [UnmarshalRecordImpl()].
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(forum15597322.BaseDataFile --> [])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.missingClassIndicatorField(DescriptorException.java:957)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLRelationshipMappingNodeValue.processChild(XMLRelationshipMappingNodeValue.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.startElement(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl.startElement(UnmarshalRecordImpl.java:834)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLReader.parse(XMLReader.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:895)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:123)
    at forum15597322.Demo.main(Demo.java:23)
```

---

**IGNORING THE ERROR**

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations including MOXy report exceptions encountered during marshalling/unmarshaling to a `ValidationEventHandler` the default one will error out when a missing inheritance indicator value is encountered.  Below is an example of setting a custom `ValidationEventHandler` that says never error out by returning `true` from the `handleEvent` method.

```
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

    });
```

While putting this answer together I found the following MOXy bug which as a result of doing the above will put an invalid text value as an item in the collection.  The fix is targeted against EclipseLink 2.5.1.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/404269

Once that fix goes in the invalid entry will just be ignored.  Is this the behaviour you are looking for?

---

**FOR MORE INFORMATION**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: Sorry for mix-up, but if handleEvent method returning true, I have invalid values within entity after unmarshalling. So, I'm still waiting fix this situation.

Comment: @EvgeniyFitsner - You can use the following bug to track our progress on this issue:  http://bugs.eclipse.org/404269