# JAXB inheritance - unmarshalling to subtypes declared in annotations?

Tags: inheritance, jaxb, moxy, subclass

I'd like to unmarshall JAXB beans into subclasses, based on attribute value.

MOXy can do that:

```
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
public static class ActionDef extends ContainerOfStackableDefs { ... }

@XmlDiscriminatorValue("cli")
public static class CliActionDef extends ActionDef {
    /** CLI command. EL. */
    @XmlAttribute public String command;
}
```

However, the `JAXBContext` needs all the classes specified. Which is kind of unpleasant to define somewhere else than in the "root" class.

I was hoping for something like:

```
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
@XmlSubClasses({ CliActionDef.class, XsltActionDef.class, ... })
public static class ActionDef extends ContainerOfStackableDefs { ... }
```

I don't want to get into `XmlAdapter`s, this is a trivial task and should have trivial solution.

**Is there something, either spec or MOXy extension, I could use to simply list the subclasses in the root class?**

Otherwise, I'm about to use Jandex to find the subclasses automatically. Afterall, MOXy could do that too ;-)

---

Update: For the record, then I was getting

```
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.jboss.loom.migrators._ext.MigratorDefinition$ActionDef --> [])
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.missingClassIndicatorField(DescriptorException.java:957)
    ...
```

Which is described here: [Exception : "Missing class indicator field from database row [UnmarshalRecordImpl()]." when unmarshalling XML using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597322/exception-missing-class-indicator-field-from-database-row-unmarshalrecordimp)

In short: Don't have MOXy unmarshalling to the same-named property as is the name in `@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@name")`. If you do, then have it `@XmlReadOnly` and don't have the class abstract.

---

Update: I still can't get it work. I keep getting the base class. Processed by MOXy, not JDK's impl.

My code:

```
    <action type="xslt" var="addAction" ...>
    </action>

    <action type="manual">
        ...
    </action>
```

Beans:

```
//@XmlRootElement
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
@XmlSeeAlso({ CliActionDef.class, ModuleActionDef.class, CopyActionDef.class, XsltActionDef.class })
public static class ActionDef extends ContainerOfStackableDefs {
    //@XmlAttribute
    //@XmlReadOnly
    public String typeVal; // Was type, caused an exception.

    //public List<PropertyBean> properties;
    //@XmlAnyAttribute
    public Map<String, String> attribs = new HashMap();
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("manual")
public static class ManualActionDef extends ActionDef {
}

public static class FileBasedActionDef extends ActionDef {
    /** Path mask. Ant-like wildcards, EL. */
    @XmlAttribute public String pathMask;

    /** Where to store the result. May be a dir or a file. EL. */
    @XmlAttribute public String dest;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("xslt")
public static class XsltActionDef extends FileBasedActionDef {
    /** XSLT template path. */
    @XmlAttribute public String xslt;
}
```

What's wrong?

**Update:**

After putting @XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type") to the top-most class `ContainerOfStackableDefs`, I get:

```
Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [manual] of type [class java.lang.String].
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.jboss.loom.migrators._ext.MigratorDefinition$ActionDef --> [])
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.missingClassForIndicatorFieldValue(DescriptorException.java:938)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.QNameInheritancePolicy.classFromRow(QNameInheritancePolicy.java:264)
```

In short: Missing `java.lang.String`. :-o Solvable?

---

Also, I created a simplest test case:

```
public class JaxbInheritanceTest {    
    @Test
    public void testUnmarshall() throws JAXBException{
        final Unmarshaller marshaller = XmlUtils.createJaxbContext(Root.class).createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = (Root) marshaller.unmarshal( new StringReader(
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<root><sub disc=\"foo\"/><sub disc=\"bar\"/></root>") );

        boolean rightClass = (DiscFoo.class.isAssignableFrom( root.subs.get(0).getClass() ));
        Assert.assertTrue( "base elements go into subclasses", rightClass );

        rightClass = (DiscBar.class.isAssignableFrom( root.subs.get(1).getClass() ));
        Assert.assertTrue( "base elements go into subclasses", rightClass );
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Root {
        @XmlElement(name = "sub")
        List<Base> subs;
    }

    @XmlDiscriminatorNode("@disc")
    @XmlSeeAlso({DiscFoo.class, DiscBar.class})
    public static abstract class Base {}

    @XmlRootElement @XmlDiscriminatorValue("foo")
    public static class DiscFoo {}

    @XmlRootElement @XmlDiscriminatorValue("bar")
    public static class DiscBar {}

}
```

But this also gives me 2x `Base`. It's handled by MOXy - checked in debugger.
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlSeeAlso` (javax.xml.bind.annotation) annotation for this.

```java
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
@XmlSeeAlso({ CliActionDef.class, XsltActionDef.class, ... })
public static class ActionDef extends ContainerOfStackableDefs { ... }
```

---

**UPDATE**

The problem you are seeing in your latest updated is caused by the `@XmlDescriminatorNode` not being placed on the root class in your inheritance hierarchy.  When I removed `ContainerOfStackableDefs` from the inheritance hierarchy using `@XmlTransient` everything worked fine (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html).

***Demo***

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

public class Demo {

    @XmlTransient
    public static class ContainerOfStackableDefs {
    }

    @XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
    @XmlSeeAlso({ ManualActionDef.class, FileBasedActionDef.class, XsltActionDef.class })
    public static class ActionDef extends ContainerOfStackableDefs {
        //@XmlAttribute
        //@XmlReadOnly
        public String typeVal; // Was type, caused an exception.

        //public List<PropertyBean> properties;
        //@XmlAnyAttribute
        public Map<String, String> attribs = new HashMap();
    }

    @XmlDiscriminatorValue("manual")
    public static class ManualActionDef extends ActionDef {
    }

    @XmlDiscriminatorValue("fileBased")
    public static class FileBasedActionDef extends ActionDef {
        /** Path mask. Ant-like wildcards, EL. */
        @XmlAttribute public String pathMask;

        /** Where to store the result. May be a dir or a file. EL. */
        @XmlAttribute public String dest;
    }

    @XmlDiscriminatorValue("xslt")
    public static class XsltActionDef extends FileBasedActionDef {
        /** XSLT template path. */
        @XmlAttribute public String xslt;
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Root {

        @XmlElement(name="actionDef")
        public List<ActionDef> actionDefs;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17453793/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

***input.xml/Output***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <actionDef type="manual"/>
   <actionDef pathMask="PATH MASK" dest="DEST" type="fileBased"/>
   <actionDef xslt="XSLT" type="xslt"/>
</root>
```

Comment: @OndraŽižka - No problem.  `@XmlSeeAlso` was introduced in JAXB 2.1 to solve just this problem.

Comment: BTW, would you consider adding that Jandex solution, for cases when I don't really know subclasses beforehand? E.g. plugins etc.

Comment: @OndraŽižka - Would you mind entering an enhancement request for this?:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink

Comment: And (excuse for misusing SO for this questions) - is there some CDI & MOXy integration considered / in progress? Could be cool to have various factory methods, adapters etc resolved by CDI.

Comment: Regarding the inheritance root - I think it makes sense to claim the hierarchy root for JAXB at arbitrary level. I need the `ContainerOfStackableDefs` as it captures common features of other structures loaded by from JAXB. Is that elligible for an enhancement request?

Comment: @OndraŽižka - In your application do you ever get an instance of `ContainerOfStackableDefs` or have a mapped field/property of that type?

Comment: Yes, `ContainerOfStackableDefs` contains common unmarshalled subelements. I'll try to move `@XmlDiscriminatorType` there.

Comment: Figured everything out. What it needed was to clean up my code and review all the details. I've reported few usability enhancement requests though: 413007, 412957, 412255.

Comment: I also created several test cases for variations of inheritance, let me know if you'd like to add them to your testsuite. Thanks for patient explaining :)